# Is there a straight-forward way to iterate over all shortcodes in a post?

Tags: posts, shortcode

I'm working with a shortcode `[translate lang=eng]Apple[/translate]` which will be shown only if the "current language" is `eng`. If the post contains, in addition to the above, the declaration `[translate lang=rus]Яаблоко[/translate]` and the current language is neither `rus` nor `eng`, neither of `Яаблоко` or `Apple` is printed.

My objective is to print the message in the default language when current language does not match that of the `[translate lang]` attribute. This implies that the message (in the default language) will be printed as many times as `[translate]` is used in the post, but that's for me to worry about...

What I need to know is if there is a `get_shortcodes()` function what will give me an `array` (or whatever) of all shortcodes in the post. Would I have to parse the post with regex if not? Do you have better suggestions?

*Please refrain from telling me about "superior" translation plugins.*

Comment: Why can't you do it when the `translate` codes are dealt with by `do_shortcodes`? Remember that you can set a plugin-specific flag so you don't do stuff multiplt times if you don't want it to.

Answer (score 1):

That's the best I can come up with:

```
function wpse20389_show_shortcode_tags()
{
    echo '<pre>Shortcode Tags: ';
        print_r( $GLOBALS['wp_filter']['the_content'] );
    echo '</pre>';
}
add_action( 'shutdown', 'wpse20389_show_shortcode_tags' );
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a get_shortcode_regex() function in wp-include/shortcodes.php. It is used by do_shortcode() and others. It's fairly easy to adopt the regex expression.

```
global $post;

$tags = array();
$pattern = '(.?)\[(translate)\b\s+(.*?)(?:(\/))?\](?:(.+?)\[\/translate\])?(.?)';
$pattern = "/$pattern/s";
preg_match_all($pattern, $post->post_content, &$tags, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($tags as $t ){

// iterate over tags... 

}
```